# Many Developers and an Organization Apple Developer Program

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

I am enrolled in the Apple Developer Program as an Organization.

> As you know you are only allowed to create a maximum of 2 development
>   certificates and 2 distribution certificates.

**Problem:**
I have 3 developers working on the App. So, they keep deleting each others certificate to be able to create provisioning profiles. Some time it gets messy and they delete push notification certificate and then we had to regenerate the certificates to create pem files and upload it to server again cause server stops sending notifications successfully.

**How can I manage this in a clean way?**

I tried to invite them and add them as developers in apple member center. that didn't work cause developer can't do anything. But, with admin role they still see each other certificates. but at least they can create more than 2 certificates.

And I added them as admins in the iTunes connect too. not doing this caused a problem. but I am not sure. they not been able to upload a version from their Xcode with their accounts cause its like they don't have permission for upload. "upload fails after they pick the team and provisioning profile with their account".

**Anything wrong with what I said? Is that how apple wants us to handle it? or there is another way?**

Comment: Why is the down vote? can you at least give a comment. if this question place is not here. where do think it should go?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter however, where did you get the information that says that you may not have more than two profiles? You may have as many as you wish...

Comment: I said that you cant have more than 2 certificates not profiles. I am an admin of 7 apple developer programs

Comment: Sorry. Then: Where did you get the information that says that you may not have more than two certs?

Comment: I told you I am managing 7 accounts that inrolled in a developer program. on those accounts using the agent user I cant create more than 2 certificates of each type. (Dev/Prod)

Comment: apple does not have alot of information about the topic in general

Comment: do you have an account with developer program? try it urself. the option will be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

No magic trick here. You cannot have more than 2 Distribution certificates and your developer will have to manually share those and the associated private keys. I believe this is legacy as a while ago only the Team Agent was authorized to manage the Distribution certificate.

Have a look at tools like https://github.com/fastlane/match which automates the sharing process and solved the issue for my agency.

Nicolas